# How to access json file in jupyter?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to access the json file and convert to it dataframe but show's invalid argument.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd
a='https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/daily/point?parameters=WS10M_MAX&community=RE&longitude=85.1500&latitude=25.6100&start=20210101&end=20210331&format=JSON'
data = json.load(open(a))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Error is-

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/daily/point?parameters=WS10M_MAX&community=RE&longitude=85.1500&latitude=25.6100&start=20210101&end=20210331&format=JSON'
```

Comment: You can't use the builtin `open()` to get the contents of a URL. Use `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

Use requests:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/climatology/point'
parameters  = { "parameters": "T2M",
               "community": "SB",
               "longitude": 0,
               "latitude" : 0,
               "format" : "JSON"
               }
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=parameters)

pd.DataFrame(resp.json())
```

But probably the better way, would be using CSV (json from this API needs some preprocessing):

```py
from io import StringIO

url = 'https://power.larc.nasa.gov/api/temporal/climatology/point'
parameters  = { "parameters": "T2M",
               "community": "SB",
               "longitude": 0,
               "latitude" : 0,
               "format" : "CSV"
               }
resp = requests.get(url=url, params=parameters)
csv = StringIO(resp.text)
pd.read_csv(csv, header=9)
```

or as [M.Zhang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9347959/m-zhang) suggested:

```py
import urllib
pd.read_csv(f'{url}?{urllib.parse.urlencode(parameters)}', header=9)
```

Comment: As a bonus, `pd.read_csv` actually works with HTTP(S) URLs.

Comment: True, thanks, I updated my answer!